# Hyperlink to a specific paragraph in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a site that has dropdown text boxes. At the moment, in the copy from "dropdownA" I have a hyperlink to "dropdownB" using:

```
<a href="javascript:void(ShowDropdown('dropdownB'))" class="dropdownB">DropdownB</a>
```

The client would like me to not only hyperlink to "dropdownB", but a specific paragraph in "dropdownB", let's say "p3". How would one link to "dropdownB, p3"?

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Putting a name on an anchor is [deprecated](http://derickrethans.nl/html-name-attribute-deprecated.html), as albert noted, so you can just put an id on the paragraph you want to link to

```
<p id="targetInDropDownB">blah blah blah</p>
```

and then link to it

```
<a href="#targetInDropDownB">Go to target paragraph</a>
```

Comment: name is deprecated, use an id on the paragraph

Comment: Thank you. This is the same method I was trying, but it didn't work because I was also using `code`<a name="targetInDropDownB"></a>`code` It works once I use id instead of name.

Comment: thanks @albert I was posting my discovery at the time you posted your comment.

Comment: np guys. you had the right idea. everything's changing so fast, it's impossible to keep up on your own. that's why we all flock here. :)